# ipython passwd not able to import with new 2022 Anaconda download

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython

I am simply trying to do this

`from IPython.lib import passwd`

but I get this error

```
In [1]: from IPython.lib import passwd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from IPython.lib import passwd

ImportError: cannot import name 'passwd' from 'IPython.lib' (/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/lib/__init__.py)
```

Googled the error but nothing.

Comment: Correct answer should be updated to eMMe's answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am facing the same issue with IPython version 8.4. It seems to me that the security lib is not present anymore.
If you are using version 7x you should be able to import it with

```
from IPython.lib.security import passwd
```

as denoted in
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/api/generated/IPython.lib.security.html?highlight=passwd

However, from version 8x the module security is missing...

Comment: Still not working on `8.15.0`

Answer (score 2):

The version 8x changed this again, as noted by @Blitzbirnep, but the new module is mentioned in the [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#automatic-password-setup)

```py
from notebook.auth import passwd
hash=passwd('example')
```

Please note that the default hashing algorithm is no more SHA1, so if you want exactly the old behavior you need to add another parameter.

```py
from notebook.auth import passwd
hash=passwd('example', 'sha1')
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of `passwd` depends on the version.

```py
#notebook==7.0.6
from jupyter_server.auth import passwd
passwd(password, 'sha1')
```

```py
#notebook==6.4.0
from IPython.lib import passwd
passwd(password)
```

You can always read the [latest manual to configure public server](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/public-server.html) to check the latest API or track change in [jupyter_server/auth/security.py#L79](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/blob/444138ccc1aa435f36fe3c43bd5640d4ef32c92b/jupyter_server/auth/security.py#L79).

Answer (score 0):

try it, worked for me.

```
import IPython.lib.security as security
security.passwd()
```

[image: Code and output]